# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in post express route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing out some updated JSON content in the post method of my route but I encounter the `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` error message when the process finishes. The JSON file does get updated but it crashes the server. I'm guessing the `generateHTML` operation hasn't finished or is causing some other issue.

I've verified that the JSON going into the fs.writeFile method is valid.

```
...
var page = {"json": "data"};
fs.writeFile('files/page.json', JSON.stringify(page), (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  res.render('page', {output: generateHTML(page)});    
});

function generateHTML(item) {
  var file = loadJSON('files/' + item + '.json');
  ...
  // Generate HTML content and return it to the variable to serve to targetPage.ejs
  ...
}

function loadJSON(json) {
  var file = fs.readFileSync(json, 'utf8');
  return JSON.parse(file);
}
```

Full error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at loadJSON (/Users/foobar/web/application/app.js:337:17)
    at /Users/foobar/web/application/app.js:251:23
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at next (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:966
    if (err) return req.next(err);
                        ^

TypeError: req.next is not a function
    at done (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:966:25)
    at tryRender (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:642:5)
    at Function.render (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/foobar/web/application/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
    at fs.writeFile (/Users/foobar/web/application/app.js:214:25)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

Comment: post your full `generateHTML`, also what is `loadJSON`

Comment: It seems it should be `generateHTML('page')`

Comment: It's not `req.next`, it's [`(req, res, next) => { /* ... */; next(); }`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

Comment: generateHTML is a function that takes an object (note the recent edit) and generates HTML content that will eventually be passed to the ejs page in the res.render method (like this: `res.render('targetPage', {page: page});'.